# Can the Cisco SF302-08 switch support IP routing capabilities?

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan

I'm currently working on configuring inter-VLAN routing on a Cisco SF302-08 switch. I've already enabled Layer 3 routing, created the VLANs, assigned them to switchports, and configured the switch VLAN interfaces accordingly. However, I'm encountering difficulties at the step where I need to configure a routed port or a static route. Despite attempting these configurations, I'm unable to achieve successful communication between the different VLANs.

The switch's configuration:

```
show running-config:

v1.4.0.88 / R800_NIK_1_4_194_194 CLI v1.0 set system mode router

! vlan database vlan 10,20 exit

interface vlan 1 
ip address 101.205.25.252 255.255.255.0  
no ip address dhcp 
!
interface vlan 10 
ip address 101.205.10.1 255.255.255.0 
! 
interface vlan 20  
ip address 101.205.20.1 255.255.255.0 
! 
interface fastethernet3  
switchport mode access  
switchport access vlan 10 
! 
interface fastethernet4  
switchport mode access  
switchport access vlan 20 
! 
interface fastethernet5  
switchport trunk allowed vlan add 10,20 
! 
interface fastethernet7  
switchport mode access  
switchport access vlan 10 
! 
interface fastethernet8  
switchport mode access  
switchport access vlan 20 
! 
exit 
ip route 101.205.10.0 /24 101.205.25.254
```

Consequently, I am seeking assistance to resolve this issue. Any guidance or support offered would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not see where you turned on routing. It is the `ip routing` global command. Also, your `ip route 101.205.10.0 /24 101.205.25.254` command should not be there. A router (a layer-3 switch also has a router module) will automatically route between directly connected networks.

Comment: @RonMaupin 
I attempted to execute the "ip routing" command, but the output indicates that it is unrecognized.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Small-business switches are somewhat unlike 'normal' Cisco switches.

1. `set system mode router` - enables routing, switch is in L2-only mode by default (deletes configuration and reboots)
2. `ip address <address> <mask/length>` from either port, VLAN or port channel context - VLAN is the most common
3. `ip route <prefix> <mask/length> <gateway>` - adds a static route for each *remote* subnet that is required. Subnets that are directly attached (see 2.) do not require nor use a static route.

See https://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/csbms/sf30x_sg30x/administration_guide/CLI_300_1_2_5.pdf for details.

Answer (score 0):

Some switches also need `sdm prefer lanbase-routing` in global configuration mode to enable routing. After that you may try to `reload`, and set `ip routing`

`sdm prefer` changes how the switch's ASIC allocates memory for different tables, `sdm prefer lanbase-routing` allows memory to be allocated to routing.